How do I export comments on Google docs/sheets using Google apps script?
We work across several Google docs/sheets to keep track of various projects. In these files we leave comments on various text/cells.
I want to compile all these comments into a sheet so we can use that to see open comments across all our docs. I'll put the function on an event trigger so we have an updated list since we're constantly adding/resolving comments. I created this script with some AI help, which looks mostly right except that the actual functions to get comments aren't working. I can't tell from the API documentation how to actually pull comments. Thoughts?
function getUnresolvedDocumentComments() {
  // Get the "Open Comments" sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var documentUrls = sheet.getRange("L2:L").getValues().flat();

  // Get the "Open Comments" sheet for output
  var resultSheet = sheet;

  // Clear the existing data in the "Open Comments" sheet, starting from row 2, but excluding column L
  resultSheet.getRange(2, 1, resultSheet.getLastRow() - 1, resultSheet.getLastColumn() - 1).clearContent();

  // Set the headers for the "Open Comments" sheet
  resultSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue("Comment Link");
  resultSheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue("Commenter");
  resultSheet.getRange(1, 3).setValue("Comment Text");

  var row = 2;
  for (var i = 0; i < documentUrls.length; i++) {
    var documentUrl = documentUrls[i];

    // Determine the document type based on the URL
    if (documentUrl.includes('/docs.google.com/document/d/')) {
      // Google Doc
      var documentId = documentUrl.split('/d/')[1].split('/')[0];
      var document = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
      var comments = DriveApp.getComments.list(documentId).items;
    } else if (documentUrl.includes('/docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/')) {
      // Google Sheet
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(documentUrl);
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
      var comments = DriveApp.getComments.list(documentId).items
    } else {
      // Unsupported document type
      Logger.log('Unsupported document type: ' + documentUrl);
      continue;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < comments.length; j++) {
      var comment = comments[j];
      if (!comment.isResolved()) { // Check if the comment is unresolved
        var commenter = comment.getUser().getEmail();
        var commentText = comment.getContent();
        var commentUrl = comment.getUrl(); // Get the direct URL to the comment

        resultSheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(commentUrl);
        resultSheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(commenter);
        resultSheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(commentText);
        row++;
      }
    }
  }
}

